# Mapreduce & Python: Bigrams

Tags: python, mapreduce

I am looking to alter my map reduce files to output the top bigrams in a chunk of text instead of the word count, so both words and the bigram count

This is my current code and approach.

Map:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    words = line.split()  #bigrams = line.split()
    for word in words:    #for bigram in words
        print '%s\t%s' % (word,1)  #print ... word pair???
```

Reduce:

```
mydict = dict() 
for line in sys.stdin:
    (word,cnt) = line.strip().split('\t') #bigram and bigram count
    mydict[word] = mydict.get(word,0) 1

for word,cnt in mydict.items():
    print word,cnt                      #print bigram and bigram count
```

Thank you.

I saw nltk as a popular solution for computing bigrams, should I have that approach even in my mapreduce format?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it with stdin and stdout. I'd rather throw [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) at this and read from some saved file:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def main(infilepath):
    bgqIn, bgqOut = [mp.Queue() for _ in xrange(2)]
    procs = [mp.Process(target=mapper, args=(bgqIn, bgqOut)) for _ in xrange(mp.cpu_count())]
    for p in procs:
        p.start()
    with open(infilepath) as infile:
        first = ''
        second = ''
        for line in infile:
            line = line.lower()
            for word in line.split():
                first = second
                second = word
                bigram = (first, second)
                bgqIn.put(bigram)
        for p in procs:
            bgqIn.put(None)

    rqs = [(mp.Queue() for _ in xrange(2)) for i in xrange(mp.cpu_count())]
    rprocs = [mp.Process(target=reducer, args=(*rqs[i])) for i in xrange(mp.cpu_count())]
    for p in rprocs:
        p.start()
    qmap = {}
    for char in xrange(97,123):
        qmap[ord(char)] = rqs[(char-97)/len(rqs)]
    dones = 0
    while dones != len(procs):
        t = bgqOut.get()
        if t is None:
            dones += 1
        else:
            qmap[t[0][0]].put(t)
    for q in rqs:
        q.put(None)

    answer = {}
    for q in rqs:
        for bg,count in iter(q.get, None):
            if bg not in answer:
                answer[bg] = 0
            answer[bg] += count

    for bg,count in answer.iteritems():
        print "There are", count, "occurrences of", bg

def mapper(qIn, qOut):
    counts = {}
    for bg in iter(qIn.get, None):
        if bg not in counts:
            counts[bg] = 0
        counts[bg] += 1
    for k,v in counts.iteritems():
        qOut.put((k,v))
    qOut.put(None)

def reducer(qIn, qOut):
    counts = {}
    for bg,count in iter(qIn.get, None):
        if bg not in counts:
            counts[bg] = 0
        counts[bg] += count
    for bg,count in counts.iteritems():
        qOut.put((bg,count))
    qOut.put(None)
```

I haven't tested this, but it's a basic skeleton that should get you started.